# How do I set the 'Application' from the Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET?

Tags: force.com-toolkit-for-net

I am using the Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET to send and retrieve data from my Salesforce client.  We have two different apps that are using the same login, and on occasion I would like to know which app has logged in.

It seems like Salesforce already has a solution for this in the Login History for the user.  There is a field called 'Application', that apparently is already settable through the API. Is there any way that this Application can be set via the Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET?  It appears in the screenshot below that the Application has already been customized, however the 'SN Salesforce Integration' does not exist anywhere in our code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This field is only set via the Partner API and/or Connected Apps. If you're using SOAP, you need to [use the Partner API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_calloptions.htm#topic-title), and if you're using REST, it should happen automatically based on the Client ID you specify.